# Is there an HTML5 validator that will point out unclosed tags (even if valid)?

Tags: html, validation, w3c-validation

In HTML5, closing certain elements (under certain circumstances) is optional, but what if I want all my tags closed for consistency? Does anyone know of a validator that would point them out? It would be ideal if this validator would be able to check local files.

I know there are reasons why you would like to not close all your tags, but in this case, I'm trying to teach someone to code, and I would like them to do it in a consistent, thoughtful manner. It would be a sort of training wheels.

Thanks

Comment: http://validator.w3.org

Comment: Thanks, but the W3C validator won't point out missing unclosed tags, unless they are invalid. You can have the <html> and <body> tags missing, and it would still show up as valid.